# why sonar:sonar needs mvn install before?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

official documentation http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven says that the proper way of invoking sonar is:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
mvn sonar:sonar
```

but doesn't say why. how does sonar work? does it need compiled classes? so why not just `mvn clean compile`? or does it need a jar file? so why not just `mvn clean package`? what exactly does sonar plugin?

Comment: If I'm not wrong some of the analysis is made directly against the jar/war/ear final file. Which makes sense as it is what you are going to use in production.

Comment: so why not `mvn clean package`?

Comment: I never skipped tests and sonar worked fine for me

Answer (score 3):

Explanation from a [SonarSource team member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31032821/3429133):

> In a multi-module build an aggregator plugin can't resolve dependencies from target folder. So you have two options:
>
> - `mvn clean install` && `mvn sonar:sonar` as two separate processes
> - `mvn clean package sonar:sonar` as a single reactor

I was surprised too, so I made a [tweet](https://twitter.com/beatngu1101/status/1357798959314591752) an received the following [answer from the official Maven account](https://twitter.com/ASFMavenProject/status/1357800064735977474):

> If the plugin is not designed to use the target/classes folder as a substitute, then yes you would need to have installed to get the jar when running *in a different session*. **Complain to the plugin author if they force you to use install without foo reason** [ed - [@connolly_s](https://twitter.com/connolly_s)]

Answer (score 1):

The SonarQube analyzer indeed needs compiled classes (e.g for Findbugs rules, coverage). And since by default it executes tests itself, the compile phase can skip tests.

Comment: i understand the skipTests part. but why `install`? why not just `mvn clean package`?

Comment: Probably that `package` is enough, YMMV (depending on other build stages/plugins between `compile` and `install`).

Answer (score 1):

You can run SonarQube as part of a single Maven command if you meet some requirements:

- As Mithfindel mentions, some SonarQube plugins need to analyze .class files. And if you run unit tests outside of SonarQube, then of course the testing plugins must read output from the `test` phase.
- Got integration tests? Then you need to run after the `integration-test` phase.
- If you want to run SonarQube as a true quality gate then you absolutely must run it before the `deploy` phase.

One solution is to just attach SonarQube to run after the `package` phase. Then you can get a full build with a simple `clean install` or `clean deploy`. Most people do not do this because SonarQube is time-consuming, but the incremental mode added in 4.0 and greatly improved in the upcoming 4.2 solves this.

As far as the official documentation goes, it's a lot easier to say "build and then run `sonar:sonar`" then it is to say, "open your POM, add a `build` element for the sonar-maven-plugin, attach it to `verify`, etc".

One caveat. SonarQube requires Java 6, so if you're building against JDK 1.5 (still common in large organizations), the analysis will have to happen in a separate Maven invocation with a newer JDK selected. We solved this issue with custom Maven build wrapper.

Comment: but from the documentations: sonar runs it's own tests so they advice to use `-DskipTests=true`

Comment: It's a YMMV, not a hard rule. SonarQube doesn't need to run tests. In fact, if you've got a complex environment it can be much preferable to just run tests beforehand. There's been talk of ending this behavior, anyway. It was always weird for SonarQube to act as a test runner.