# What maven goal is required to run maven sonar analysis?

Tags: sonarqube, maven-3

I have seen sonar builds failing if I run `mvn package` or `mvn verify` as build goals, however if I change it to `mvn install` it passes.

Can you explain why maven install goal is needed for sonar to work properly?

Comment: Can you give more informations like SonarQube version and maven logs ? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why sonar:sonar needs mvn install before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221679/why-sonarsonar-needs-mvn-install-before)

Answer (score 2):

In a multi-module build an aggregator plugin can't resolve dependencies from target folder. So you have two options:

- `mvn clean install` && `mvn sonar:sonar` as two separate processes
- `mvn clean package sonar:sonar` as a single reactor